# Can I suppress mysqldump's timestamp?

Tags: mysql

I'm using `mysqldump -T` to dump the contents of a database to individual table files.  I want to compare these files to a similar set of dump files made at a different time.

When I try comparing the file sets (using `diff`, for example), the output is swamped in the noise of the timestamp that `mysqldump` adds to each file:

```
Dump completed on 2020-04-23 11:40:32
```

Even if nothing substantial has changed between the two files, they still register as a diff because of these lines.  Is there a way to suppress these timestamps from the output of `mysqldump -T`?

Comment: Do you mean `--skip-dump-date`?

Comment: Exactly, yes.  I was searching the docs by "timestamp", which doesn't appear in the section on `--skip-dump-date`, so I missed it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Progman commented above, the mysqldump tool has an option `--skip-dump-date`.

If you need to diff dumps that have already been made, I'd suggest:

```
diff -I '^-- Dump completed on' ...
```

I just made two mysqldumps of my test database, and they have different timestamps. The `diff -I` option was effective at filtering that out.

```
$ diff -r dump1 dump2

diff -r dump1/foo.sql dump2/foo.sql
52c52
< -- Dump completed on 2020-04-24 13:37:24
---
> -- Dump completed on 2020-04-24 13:38:21

$ diff -r -I '^-- Dump completed on ' dump1 dump2
$
```

Comment: That's two very useful pieces of information.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```sh
mysqldump [OPTIONS] --skip-dump-date -T PATH [DB_NAME]
```

From the manual ([MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_dump-date), [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqldump/)):

> the date causes dump files taken at different times to appear to be different, even if the data are otherwise identical. `--dump-date` and `--skip-dump-date` control whether the date is added to the comment. The default is `--dump-date` (include the date in the comment). `--skip-dump-date` suppresses date printing.